# Cannot read secret variable from AWS SSM Get Parameter task in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My Azure DevOps pipeline has a "AWS SSM Get Parameter" task that reads the parameters into build variables.  I can reference these variables successfully using "$(BuildVariableName)" syntax, as long as they are not secret parameters, but for any parameter where "is secret = true", the value of the variable is "***".  What do I need to do to be able to read the secret parameters as build variables?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most desirable solution, but I was able to partially get this to work by using a Powershell task to copy the secure variable to a non-secure variable.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NonSecureVariable;]$(SecureVariable)"
```

However, if $(SecureVariable) contains "$", then all of the characters after the "$" are truncated.  Is there a way to get access to the secure variable other than Powershell, or is there a way to get Powershell to work with special characters?